# How to create the sql database according the book "iText in action" examples

Tags: database-design, itext, hsqldb

I'm trying to start chapter 2 of the book and there we need to create a database "filmfestival" in the folder "resources/db/".
I prepared all scripts in the folder "resources/scripts/", but I can't seem to get the database created.
Any ideas what am I missing?
Regards,
Job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me walk you through this step by step.

First you need to be sure that you have the hsqldb.jar in your CLASSPATH. You can check this using this line:

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
```

If this jdbcDriver isn't available, you won't be able to use the database I created for my book.

Second step: make a connection:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:hsqldb:resources/db/filmfestival", "SA", "");
```

Don't worry about the `"SA"` (username) and `""` (password). This is a test database, it doesn't need to be protected. Take a look at the `resources/db/filmfestival` part. It means that there's a directory `resources/db` that can be reached from the working directory of your application, and that this working directory contains a file names [filmfestival.script](http://examples.itextpdf.com/resources/db/filmfestival.script).

Once you make this connection, you'll see that one to three extra files are created in the `db` directory (some are temporary files, such as the lock file ending in `.lck`). By the way: the code snippets are taken from [`HsqldbConnection`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=2) and [`DatabaseConnection`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=1).

You now have a connection to the database. Time to create a statement and to perform a query. The example [DatabaseTest](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=13) shows how it's done.

```
Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT country FROM film_country ORDER BY country");
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("country"));
}
stm.close();
connection.close();
```

As you can see, this code isn't any different from the JDBC code you'd write for any other database. I've chosen HypersonicSQL for only one reason: anyone can use it without having to install a full blown database system. All you need is an extra jar and a script file.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for you r response. I'm already able to make a connection to the database, and can see the temporary files that are created when running the DatabaseTest class. But now I'm dealing with another problem: "object not found: FILM_COUNTRY".

Comment: Hi Bruno, Sorry my mistake. I forgot to run the "CreateHsqldbTables" class to create all tables. I can continue to work your examples. by the way, thanks for the nicely illustrated book.

Answer (score 0):

The database files should built there . At the new databAse page choose the address you want and see files there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely what you mean. I think that there should be a class that have a main method, which will execute the scripts that are in the resource folder.